# Understanding file stream flags/bits

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream, flags

I think that I currently don't understand well the mechanisms of the io stream flags. To try to understand that, I will ask questions on two specific examples.

---

The first one concern the open mode.
For example, for std::ofstream we have :

```
void open ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );

app (append) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation.
ate (at end) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening.
binary  (binary) Consider stream as binary rather than text.
in  (input) Allow input operations on the stream.
out (output) Allow output operations on the stream.
trunc   (truncate) Any current content is discarded, assuming a length of zero on opening.
```

I have the following questions :

```
std::ofstream stream;

// Question 1 : Here I don't specify std::ios::out, so why does it work ? :
stream.open("file.txt", std::ios::binary);

// Question 2 : Here I activate trunc, but how can I deactivate it ?
stream.open("file.txt", std::ios:binary | std::ios::trunc);

// Question 3 : What would be the result of that ?
stream.open("file.txt", std::ios::in);
```

---

The second one concern the state flags. Consider the following example :

```
std::ofstream stream;
std::cout<<stream.good()<<stream.bad()<<stream.fail()<<stream.eof()<<std::endl;
stream<<'x';
std::cout<<stream.good()<<stream.bad()<<stream.fail()<<stream.eof()<<std::endl;
/* SOMETHING */
```

As no file is opened, the result is :

```
1000 // <- Good bit is true
0110 // <- Fail and bad bit are true
```

**Question 4 :** what is the piece of code that I can write instead of `/* SOMETHING */`, to reset the `badbit` to `false` and to set the `eofbit` to `true` (this operation has no meaning here, but it is just to understand the behaviour of these bits).

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

1. You're calling open on an `std::ofstream`.  The definition of
   `std::ofstream::open` is:

   ```
   rdbuf()->open( name, mode | std::ios_base::out );
   ```

   In other words, `std::ofstream` always adds the `out` bit when opening.
2. You can add `std::ios_base::app` to the mode flags, but this will 
   have the effect of forcing every write to the end of file, regardless of
   where you might be positionned before.  (This is probably what you want
   if you're opening in write only.)  Otherwise, if you open with both
   `std::ios_base::in` and `sdt::ios_base::out`, the file will not be
   truncated.
3. The file won't be truncated:-).  While the `ofstream` doesn't provide
   any functions for reading from it, you can create an `std::istream` from
   the `streambuf` returned by `rdbuf`, and read from it.
4. In this case `stream.clear( std::ios_base::eofbit )` would do the
   trick.  But you cannot always reset `badbit`: if there is no `streambuf`
   attached, `badbit` will be set regardless of what you do.

As you might notice, the names aren't always intuitive: `clear` to set
a bit, and the logic is far from orthogonal with regards to the open
flags.